Minkowski functional as a norm
Related to my previous question. Let $X$ be a real Banach space, and $A\subset X$ a balanced, convex, absorbing set that is bounded. Then $(X, p_A)$, where $p_A$ is the minkowski functional, is a normed space. Its open unit ball $\{p_A<1 \}\subset A$ is then bounded, which means $Id: (X, p_A)\to (X, \|\cdot\|)$ is a bounded operator.

Question. If $A$ happens to have empty interior, does it mean $(X, p_A)$ cannot be complete?

If the latter space is Banach, since $Id$ is bijective, by the open mapping theorem, its inverse is also bounded, and hence $A$ should be a neighborhood of $0$ under the original norm $\|\cdot\|$. Is that correct? If so, this would be an example of a bounded operator with an unbounded inverse. Thanks in advance.
Update. It seems we can even further conclude: a bounded, balanced, convex, absorbing subset $A\subset X$ is a neighborhood of $0$ under the original norm iff $(X, p_A)$ is a Banach space.
